# Need training data for categories like Sports, Entertainment, Health etc and all the sub categories

Tags: text, machine-learning, wikipedia, document-classification

I am experimenting with Classification algorithms in ML and am looking for some corpus to train my model to distinguish among the different categories like sports,weather, technology, football,cricket etc,

I need some pointers on where i can find some dataset with these categories,

Another option for me, is to crawl wikipedia to get data for the 30+ categories, but i wanted some brainstorming and  opinions, if there is a better way to do this.

### Edit

Train the model using the bag of words approach for these categories
Test - classify new/unknown websites to these predefined categories depending on the content of the webpage.

Comment: What are you trying to categorize? Images? News reports? Audio commentary?

Comment: i am trying to classify webpages(only the text from the webpages)

Comment: Might this be better suited for [Stats.SE](http://stats.stackexchange.com/)?

Answer (score 4):

The [UCI machine learning repository](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/) contains a searchable archive of datasets for supervised learning.

You might get better answers if you provide more specific information about what inputs and outputs your ideal dataset would have.

**Edit:**

- It looks like [dmoz has a dump that you can download](http://rdf.dmoz.org/).
- [A dataset of newsgroup messages](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs.cmu.edu/project/theo-20/www/data/news20.html), classified by subject